# Kotlin sort hashmap in descending order

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have `val myHashMap = HashMap<String, MutableList<TestItem>>()`, hashmap key value is formatted date as a string for example `20-06-2018` how can I sort this hashMap in descending order?

expected result:

```
22-06-2018 : []
21-06-2018 : []
20-06-2018 : []
```

I use this code to sort it, but result is in ascending order:

```
val sortedMap = myHashMap.toSortedMap(compareBy { it })
```

Comment: Your expected result seems to also be in descending order? Also, the `toSortedMap` call you have there works perfectly for me, and I get the elements in ascending order (20, 21, 22).

Comment: my mistake, updated question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [`compareByDescending`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by-descending.html):

```
val sortedMap = myHashMap.toSortedMap(compareByDescending { it })
```

Comment: Thank you! Kotlin is awesome

Comment: Indeed, almost everything is already there in the standard library :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
val sortedMap = myHashMap.toSortedMap(reverseOrder())
```

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/reverse-order.html.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the result in ascending order is because (from the values you presented) all dates have month=6 and year=2018. 
If there are various dates then if you simply do `compareByDescending` the result will be wrong. 
Consider these dates:
21-05-2018, 22-4-2018. 
If you sort descending you will get 1st 22-04-2018!  
What you need to do is convert the dates in yyyy-MM-dd and then sort descending:

```
fun convertDate(d: String): String {
    val array = d.split("-")
    return array[2] + array[1] + array[0]
}

val sortedMap =  myHashMap.toSortedMap(compareByDescending { convertDate(it) })
```

One more thing: your dates must have 2 digits for month and day and 4 digits for year, dates like 2-5-2018 will give wrong result.
  
**Last edit**: no need for `-` in the concatenation.